# Impact on database log file of SQL Server.

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

One of my website is very slow, i have just seen that database log file(ldf) size is too big around 20GB, even mdf file size is only 9GB. Is there any big impact performance on website?

And Suppose, I use SHRINKFILE command then website performance will be better or not.

Answer (score 0):

No, logfile size does not impact the database performance as long as the disk is not running out of space. If the recovery model is Simple you can just shrink the logfile, otherwise you must backup the database first.

Answer (score 0):

Like Danile said, i dont think log files are the cause for your performance. YOu can run the query below and:

1.Check the execution times of the stored procedures. 
2.When identify long running stored procedures, you can optimize them 
3. another trick ( though its only a quick fix ) is to recompile the stored procesure, so the latested plan is always on proc cache. 
4. Also, consider updated status, rebuild index

```
SELECT @@servername server, db_name() db, b.name object,
    --a.min_elapsed_time,
    --a.max_elapsed_time,
    --a.last_elapsed_time as last_elapsed_time_microsec,
    --a.last_worker_time as last_worker_time_microsec,
    (a.last_worker_time/1000) as last_worker_time_millisecond,
    a.last_logical_reads,
    a.cached_time,
       a.last_execution_time
      -- a.last_elapsed_time as last_elapsed_time_microseconds ---Elapsed time, in microseconds, for the most recently completed execution of this stored procedure.
       --CONVERT(varchar, last_elapsed_time, 120)
       --((a.last_elapsed_time / 1000 )) as millie_seconds,
       --((a.last_elapsed_time % (1000*60*60)) % (1000*60)) / 1000 as seconds 
FROM   sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats a 
       INNER JOIN sys.objects b 
               ON a.object_id = b.object_id 
WHERE  Db_name(a.database_id) = '<your database name >' 
--and  name in('<procedure name>') --optional
```